# Custom Rules do not get imported when Quality Profile is restored on another SonarQube instance

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 5.1.2. I have created many custom rules using Rule Templates for quality profiles of both Java (plugin version 3.13.1) and C# (4.3) languages. I wanted to replicate this SonarQube instance onto a new server and hence did a Backup of the quality profiles and performed 'Restore Profile' on the new SonarQube server.

Strangely, all the custom rules are not imported on to the new SonarQube instance. Why is it so? What should I do to import the custom rules onto new SonarQube instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [SONAR-5366
Make it possible to back up and restore customizations of rules](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5366), which is not yet implemented, unfortunately.